# How can I reference a row in another sheet based on value in cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to reference entire row from another as argument in my function, normally I would use something like this:
OtherSheet!27:27

But what, if 27 is a dynamic value stored in other cell?

For example, I have MATCH function looking like this:

```
=MATCH(B6;OtherSheet!27:27;0)
```

and value 27 stored in cell A1. When I'll change the value to 28 I want my MATCH function look like this:

```
=MATCH(B6;OtherSheet!28:28;0)
```

What should I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Excel’s [`INDIRECT` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261) which allows to reference ranges specified as literal values, be they stored elsewhere, passed literally or a combination of both. Thus,

```
=MATCH(B6; INDIRECT("OtherSheet!" & A1 & ":" A1); 0)
```

will evaluate to

```
=MATCH(B6; OtherSheet!27:27; 0)
```

if cell A1 contains the value 27.

Answer (score -1):

=MATCH(B6;OtherSheet!27:27;0)
Is a search function which should return the value that is in cell 27, which may not be 27.

Change (B6;OtherSheet!27:27;0)
to (B6;OtherSheet!A1:A1), to return the value stored in cell A1.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain it clear enough - English isn't my native language, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I want my MATCH function to search row, which number is stored in cell A1. So when value stored in A1 is 27 - search OtherSheet, row 27, when value in A1 is 35 - search OtherSheet, row 35 etc.